# Android animation and move view out of its layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a GridView, I want to move one of the ImageView inside one of the item of this GridView, I want to move it on screen using a TranslateAnimation and put it in a corner of the screen for example. I'm fine with the animation, the problem is that the View can't be moved out of its layout without disappearing. Which is totally normal.

My question is: What is best way to animate a view wherever I want on the screen ? Should I add it the the main layout of my activity and then move it? Or is there is a way similar to the iOS `clipToBounds` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay found `android:clipChildren="false"`, and it works